# Mistake in reading a rms voltage

Tags: voltage, measurement, rectifier, rms, full-bridge

I got a really strange result. I've build a full-bridge rectifier with a capacitor filter. And I used the following values \$\text{C}=500\cdot10^{-6}\$ and as a load \$\text{R}=1000\$. The maximum voltage of the sine input is \$230\sqrt{2}\$. Now when I measure the rms voltage across the resistor I measure around \$391.2611\$ but that is higher than \$230\sqrt{2}\$ so there must be something wrong. Or can it be this way?

the circuit looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU15G9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Use the schematic button on the editor toolbar to create a schematic so we're all clear exactly what you've done. It will take you a couple of minutes. Upload a photo and make and model of your meter. You should probably be on the DC range.

Comment: @Transistor Done.

Comment: Good work. You may have missed my request for the meter info. I edited my comment immediately after posting it. There are a variety of "true" RMS measurement techniques that aren't true.

Comment: Your bridge rectifier orientation is incorrect. Edit and press 'R' to rotate.

Comment: @Transistor I edited my schematic. I measured it just with a regular multimeter, just with one that always shows the correct value (not a cheap one) so why does it show a strange value this time?!

Comment: What is "a regular multimeter"? Analog / digital, €5 / €250, AC / true RMS? Make and model and link to datasheet?

Comment: @Transistor Digital one and it costs around 300 euro. True RMS yes. I do not know the model. But what should it has to read to read a correct value? It looks like the multimeter that circuitspecialits offers on there website.

Comment: Do you measure 230 Vac on the AC-side?

Comment: @winny yes 230 volts RMS on the AC side, before the fullbridge

Comment: Then IF the reading is correct , the signal is not a sine wave, where does it come from?  IF incorrect, remove Cap and measure again on DC (avg)

Answer (score 1):

What you are reading is the DC peak voltage which is 1.414 times the AC input voltage, minus 2 volts for the diode drop in the rectifier. Your 1 K resistor must be the 300 watt size or it would bust into flames. In fact you should check your 1 K resistor to be sure it did not open up.

You do not have enough load to bring the voltage down. True RMS readings are done with special ICs like the AD736, which account for a distorted waveform as well as sine waves.

You *could* consider 70.7% of your DC reading as the RMS value, but it would not be accurate, especially with non-sine waves. You want true RMS, buy the low cost AD736 IC.